# Comparing custom objects from 2 arrays (iOS)

Tags: ios, arrays, sqlite, comparison, updates

**The Context :**

- Developing a social app.
- I have two arrays containing the same object types (called "Friendships").
- One is coming from the local database (localArray) and the other one is from the server (onlineArray)
- The online one is always up to date, the local one might be slightly different or exactly the same.

I need to compare them.

**The problem :**

- Each friendship has different property values (for the sake of knowing, there are scores, names, etc.).
- The two arrays don't specifically contain the same number of friendships (if a user deleted it between the two updates)
- They are not in the same order. the first object in the local array might have an ID X where the first one in the other might have an Y.

**The goal :**

Essenstially, i want to update my local database with the new content only. Its an SQLite database. 
I'd like to only update the changed fields. Say friendship #147 has an updated score, i just update the corresponding object 147 and i'm good. But knowing what has changed stops me.

**The current situation:**

Right now, i'm just **always** deleting it and recreating it with the new content which is, as you may scream right now, highly suboptimal. Here is my code (with comments)

```
+ (void)compareFriendshipsFromDb:(NSMutableArray*)friendshipsFromDb andInsert:(NSMutableArray*)friendshipsOnline{
    BOOL update = NO;  //It tells us if there is new stuff
    NSUInteger x = 0;  //It helps us compare later.

    if ([friendshipsFromDb count] != [friendshipsOnline count]){
        update = YES;  //The count is different, there MUST be something different, we update.
    }
    else{
        x = [friendshipsOnline count];  //same count, but not specifically identical.
        // i'm saving that count in 'x' because its the up-to-date count.
    }

    if (x > 0 && update == NO){  //This means that the count was identical and that there were friendships to update
        for(int i = 0; i < x ; i ++){
            //TODO: Compare with PREDICATES ? I read online that it's very powerful/optimal
            //This is how I compare right now. It's always updating right now...
            if (![friendshipsFromDb containsObject:[friendshipsOnline objectAtIndex:i]]){
                update = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Count was at zero (no friendships online) and none were found in DB. Pretty much alone.
    if (x == 0 && update == NO){
        DLog(@"There are no friends to compare");
    }
    //This is my update process, doesn't really matter.
    if (update){
        [DatabaseManager dropAndRecreateTable:@"friendships"];
        [DatabaseManager insertFriendships:friendshipsOnline];

    }
//And this calls the end of this part of the update, doesn't really matter either.
//I left these just so you have the complete process.
    else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:NOTIF_FRIENDSHIPS_DONE object:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:NOTIF_HOME_RELOAD object:self];
    }

}
```

Also, i feel like comparing each object to each other object (two for loops) is just a complete overkill and is just a waste of resources considering : 
 - I have multiple properties to compare
 - Most of the comparisons would be useless because i don't need to compare friendship X with friendship Y. I need to compare it with the new version of friendship X.

There you go, that's all I have for now but make sure to ask questions in the comments. This looks fairly easy for an experienced programmer but I don't know how i can succeed here. My brutal approach works but is just full of unecessary processes.

I'm all ears !

EDIT : Related question :

I'm always gonna work with about 10 to 50 entries in that specific table.
Is it more efficient to just keep it the way it is, or compare everything with inner forloops in ifs everywhere, and do unique db calls (but maybe 15  times in a row)?
Would it be more CPU heavy to open-update-close the db 15 times in a row or just brutally delete and insert everything as an array every time (but once) ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have wanna compare Array of product object

Prodcut.h

```
@interface Prodcut : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *firstName;
-(BOOL)isEqual:(Prodcut *)object;
@end
```

Product.m

```
#import "Prodcut.h"

@implementation Prodcut
-(BOOL)isEqual:(Prodcut *)object{
    int i = 0;
    if ([self.name isEqual:object.name]) {
        i++;
        if ([self.firstName isEqualToString:object.firstName]) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}
@end
```

Compression logic

```
Prodcut *prod1 = [[Prodcut alloc] init];
prod1.name = @"name";
prod1.firstName = @"fn1";

Prodcut *prod2 = [[Prodcut alloc] init];
prod2.name = @"name";
prod2.firstName = @"fn2";

Prodcut *prod3 = [[Prodcut alloc] init];
prod3.name = @"name";
prod3.firstName = @"fn1";

Prodcut *prod4 = [[Prodcut alloc] init];
prod4.name = @"name";
prod4.firstName = @"fn2";

NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prod1,prod2,nil];
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prod3,prod4,nil];
int i=0;
if (array1.count == array2.count) {
    for (Prodcut *pro in array1 ) {      
        for (Prodcut *innerPro in array2) {
            if ([pro isEqual:innerPro]) {
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i == array1.count) {
        NSLog(@"same");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not Same");
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Not same");
}
```